# how to open option 'Scan sources for module dependencies' of msvc 2019 in cmake

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I cannot seek out this problem in the google. May somebody give an anwser to this problem, thanks!.

Comment: I'm also currently trying to figure this out myself. I was hoping `CMAKE_CXX_SCAN_FOR_MODULES` would do it, but it doesn't seem to work.

I got it working in Premake via setting `ScanSourceForModuleDependencies`, but I'm moving to CMake, so obviously that won't work.

I'll keep at it and will let you know as soon as I figure it out